# Скрыть контекстное меню при выделении текста

Tags: javascript

Можно как-то программно скрыть это меню при выделении текста в браузере?
Вместо него хочу выводить свое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно появляется при **выделении текста без нажатия на ПКМ** (замечена в яндекс браузере и мобильном хроме при редактировании текста)

Comment: document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault()); чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/258167/

Comment: contextmenu - это событие пкма же. а эта менюшка, что на скрине, выскакивает при выделении текста в яндекс браузере (без нажатия пкм). в мобильном хроме тоже появляется что-то подобное при выделении текста. пробовал вешать событие на contextmenu => .preventDefault(). Толку нет :(

Comment: послушайте onselect или onselectstart, кмк оно там. p.s. в инспекторе всегда можно открыть DOM и в нём увидеть всех активных "слушателей".

Comment: @puffleeck Слушателей нет, а менюшка выскакивает. Это, похоже в самом браузере зашито, и через JS не перехватить. Отключается в настройках браузера Инструменты/Контекстное меню.